# Python - BytesIO and urllib2.add_data

Tags: python, ironpython, urllib2, bytesio

I have a BytesIO that I'm adding various bytes to.  I want to send this in a urllib2.Request via the request.add_data method.  How do I do this?  When I try

```
# create request ....
bytesio = BytesIO()
bytesio.write(open("C:\img.jpg", "rb").read())
request.add_data(bytesio.getvalue()) 
bytesio.close()

urllib2.urlopen(request) # error "expected buffer, got bytes"
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm new to Python and not sure how to create a buffer from a BytesIO.  Also, when I just try:

```
request.add_data(bytesio)  # instead of bytesio.getvalue()
```

I get a "I/O operation on closed file".  If I try to wait until after urlopen to call bytesio.close, then the request just hangs because it's waiting for bytesio to be closed.

What do I need to do?

**Answer**

```
request.add_data(str(btyesio.getvalue()))
bytesio.close()
```

Casting to a string made it happy.  I haven't tried to see if it all works with StringIO and I haven't tried the differences between Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution: don't use a `BytesIO`, you don't need it.

[`urllib2.Request.add_data`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2#urllib2.Request.add_data) expects it's argument to be a string, so just give it one.

the call:

```
bytesio.write(open("C:\img.jpg", "rb").read())
```

reads the whole file into memory, then writes it to `bytesio`s memory. That means you already have the string in mory, you don't need it twice. So just try:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.site.com')
with open("C:\img.jpg", "rb") as inputfile:
    request.add_data(inputfile.read())
urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: I need to add multiple items (files, plain text)...  That's why I'm was using BytesIO to build up the data before setting it on the request.

Comment: Also: you said it expects a string.  Are string and "buffer" the same?

Comment: strings in python have the same interface as [`buffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#buffer), so everything expecting a buffer can also handle a string. In python2 you should probably use `StringIO.StringIO` instead of `BytesIO`. In cPython 2.7 `bytes` is the same as `str`, maybe IronPython is different here. - and dont forget to set the `Content-Type` header if you don't want your data to be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment info, which will help as I transition this up to 3.x.  See my updated question for what ended up working!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line(add it at the end):

```
bytesio.close()
```

The other code seems to work for me:

```
bytesio = BytesIO()
bytesio.write(open("C:\img.jpg", "rb").read())
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.site.com')
request.add_data(bytesio.getvalue()) 

urllib2.urlopen(request) # error "expected buffer, got bytes"
bytesio.close()

>>In [30]: urllib2.urlopen(request)
Out[30]: <addinfourl at 52264040 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x315a450>>
```

Or using StringIO:

```
sio = StringIO.StringIO(open("C:\img.jpg", "rb").read())
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.site.com')
request.add_data(sio.getvalue()) 

urllib2.urlopen(request) # error "expected buffer, got bytes"
sio.close()

>>In [14]: urllib2.urlopen(request)
Out[14]: <addinfourl at 49067360 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x2dfb3d0>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting the "expected buffer, got bytes" error message when I use getvalue() and close() after urlopen().  I'm using IronPython 2.7, would that cause any problem/difference if this code is working for you?

Comment: So, are StringIO and BytesIO the same in Python 2.x, just not in 3.x?

Answer (score 1):

There is no BytesIO.getvalue() method because it's not needed. Instead, just keep a reference to the underlying buffer.

This works with lists and arrays, as well as bytes objects, but it's sort of a coincidence, rather than an actual design goal...

Comment: Can you please show an example of how I "keep a reference to the underlying buffer"?  I'm new to Python.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you can check here http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole data of a `BytesIO` with:

```
esio.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
esio.read()
```

(`SEEK_SET` isn't needed, but I use it to clarify things)

So your example:

```
# create request ....
bytesio = BytesIO()
bytesio.write(open("C:\img.jpg", "rb").read())
bytesio.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
request.add_data(bytesio.read()) 
bytesio.close()

urllib2.urlopen(request)
```